Как в Webpack 5 правильно сгенерировать .webp изображения из .png подключаемых в index.html, что бы после сборки проекта путь был к формату .webp?

Для сборки бандлов использую HtmlWebpackPlugin.Также для копирование изображений использую CopyWebpackPlugin.Для конвертации изображений в формат.webp ImageMinimizerPlugin.
